# Set number of columns in table with PHP

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have a piece of code which reads an XML catalog file with SimpleXMLElement and prints out the containing products of that catalog into a css styled table on a website.

The code outputs every product next to each other. 
However I only want to show 4 products in a row.

I therefore need to insert some

```
<tr> </tr>
```

tags following every 4 (or x) number of products in the array.

How should I do this? My code is as follows:

```
echo '<table class="products">';

foreach (getProdutcsFromCatalog($grpName) as $product) {


                        $output = '

                        <td>
                            <h2>' .$product->title .'</h2>
                            <div class="img">
                                <img src="' .$product->img . '" height="150" width="100" class =""/>
                            </div>  
                            <div>
                                '.$product->description.'
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="price">
                                <b>
                                    '.$product->price . ' DKK' . ' 
                                </b>
                            </div>
                            <div class="addToCart">
                                <a href="#">Læg i kurv</a>
                            </div>
                        </td>   

                        ';

                        echo $output;
                    }

                echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I don't see any `tr` tags.

Comment: That's because I can't figure out where and how to place them so I get the result that i want. My question is how should I add these tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise `$i = 0;` before starting the `foreach` loop. Then change your

```
    echo $output;
}
```

to:

```
    if( $i % 4 == 0 ) echo "<tr>";
    echo $output;
    if( $i % 4 == 3 ) echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this simple and effective solution. I've tried so many different and more advanced methods - not of them working properly. What does the % mean?

Comment: The `%` is an arithmetic operator, known as **modulus**. It returns the remainder. Here, read [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) on docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want 4 items per row I'd advise you to first loop through the XML structure and save all your items in an array, and then to `array_chunk($items, 4)` the array and then loop through it and generate the table.